# How do you reduce space between floating editText hint and editText box in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, android-textinputlayout

I have an EditText with a floating hint but I was wondering how I would reduce the space between the floating hint and the EditText box.

Right now my UI looks like https://i.stack.imgur.com/ltfra.jpg and I want to reduce the space between the "Title" floating hint and the EditText box.

Here's the code to my xml file

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" >

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp">

        <EditText
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.EditText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="40dp"
            android:hint="Title"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp">

        <EditText
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.EditText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="32dp"
            android:hint="Details"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 20):

Just set paddingTop attribute on EditText element.

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/place_name"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:hint="@string/name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="0dp"/>

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```