# TextInputLayout :How to give padding or margin to hint?

Tags: android, android-layout, androiddesignsupport, android-textinputlayout

I have to use `TextInputLayout` of design support library in my project. I want to give space between `hint` and `EditText` in `TextInputLayout`. I set margin and padding in `TextInputLayout` and even inside `EditText` but both are not work.So how to solve this issue. Here i attach screen shot and my coding.

```
==============================Style=================================

<style name="TextHint" parent="Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/green</item>
</style>



=============================XML===================================  
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextHint"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:id="@+id/edttxtEmailAddress"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:hint="@string/enter_valid_email"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_common"/>
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: why did you put the edit text in the android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout

Comment: I guess he wanted to display a hint. But... doesn't the `hint` xml tag work?

Comment: Because i want to use Floating hint for that EditText.

Comment: @Mauker no hint tag work as you see in image hint display but its overlapping EditText border..so Is there any way to give vertical distance between Hint and EditText?

Comment: @parnav please read my updated answer it contains how to show the  erro which you may wana need too as in the case of in correct things etc

Answer (score 135, accepted):

The solution proposed by ganesh2shiv works for the most part, although I've found it also de-centres the hint text displayed inside the EditText when not focused.

A better trick is to set the desired `paddingTop` to the EditText but also embed the extra padding within the EditText's background. A fairly sane way to do this is to wrap your original background in a `<layer-list>` and set the `<item android:top="...">` attribute to match the `paddingTop` of your EditText.

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">

  <EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/floating_hint_margin"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_edit_text" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

And the `bg_edit_text.xml` drawable file:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:top="@dimen/floating_hint_margin">
    <your original background; can be <bitmap> or <shape> or whatever./>
  </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: this should be the correct answer. @ganesh2shiv answer can cut the edittext background

Comment: When we add `android:top` we are creating an top insert which is space between the border line at the top and edittext top side. so border will be below edit text top side. that why we are using `android:paddingTop` to compensate for the donated space.   This answer locks!

Comment: For people who may have an error : remove `.xml` from the background identifier

Comment: Can't you do that without adding some background?

Comment: Thanks its working for me, I have just added padding to background box

Comment: Note that you must use x2 padding for your EditText to achieve default height and vertical centered input text. So if your drawable top padding is 16dp, your EditText padding must be 32dp

Comment: I need to show the floating label inside top of my input box. But it not works. Needs to show the label inside of the box. Any suggestions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65367815/floating-label-needs-to-show-inside-the-textinput-layout-in-android-studio

Comment: perfect solution. working perfectly well for me.

Comment: `<bitmap android:src="@drawable/my_image">` is what I did inside of the `<item>` tags for a PNG image that I was using as a background.

Answer (score 35):

I have been looking for the solution to this question from last couple of days myself. After tearing my hairs out for hours I have finally found a simple workaround. What I have noticed is that **if you have custom background set on EditText the android:paddingTop attribute simple doesn't work to alter the spacing b/w the hint text and edit text** (I have really no idea why). So if you have set custom background to your EditText, **you can use android:translationY attribute in the EditText**.

So here's your solution:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextHint">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edttxtEmailAddress"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_common"
        android:hint="@string/enter_valid_email"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"

        android:translationY="10dp" 

        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Hope it helps. :)

---

**Update:** My sincerest apologies for the late update. I have been really busy lately. **If you haven't realized yet let me tell you this answer is straight out ugly and wrong**. In retrospect I think I was probably drunk when I wrote it. As mentioned by others it might cut the bottom region of the editText background but there's an ugly fix for it as well - you can set the height of the (parent) textInputLayout sightly bigger (how big? you are supposed to find it by trial and error, yuck!) than the (child) editText. I hope you all do realize that would be crazy so please don't do it. Check out [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33435984/5384453) written by @Radu Topor, it's by far the best and clean solution to this question. Thanks.

Comment: well its affecting the background layout set in edittext

Comment: I just needed a little push upwards, and your solution (using 5dp) worked fine

Comment: tanks alot, need paddingBottom

Comment: this solution also worked for me but the only it cuts the bottom part a bit like you already mentioned.

Answer (score 13):

I tried the padding changes, but it doesn't work well.

A simple *workaround* is to change the height of the TIL:

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

to (e.g.)

```
android:layout_height="50dp"
```

it might not give the same result on all screen sizes.

And add

```
android:gravity="bottom"
```

to push your text down.

Comment: "it might not give the same result on all screen sizes" This is why this is a bad idea

Answer (score 12):

@RaduTopor 's answer is good, but I think we also need add android:bottom or else it also de-centres the hint text displayed inside the EditText when not focused

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:top="@dimen/floating_hint_margin" android:bottom="@dimen/floating_hint_margin">
    <your original background; can be <bitmap> or <shape> or whatever./>
  </item>
</layer-list>
```

Before(RaduTopor answer):

[image: not centered]

After:

[image: centered]

Answer (score 6):

After many attempts i found one more solution (material version 1.2.1):

this is layout sample:

```
  <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/textInputLayout"
            style="@style/CustomTextInputLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    
            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/textInputEditText"
                style="@style/CustomTextInputEditText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/hint" />

  </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

this is styles sample:

```
 <style name="CustomTextInputLayout">
        <item name="boxCollapsedPaddingTop">-16dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingTop">16dp</item>
        <item name="boxBackgroundColor">@color/backgroundColorWhite</item>
        <item name="android:textColorHint">...</item>
        <item name="android:textAppearance">...</item>
        <item name="hintTextAppearance">...</item>
        <item name="hintTextColor">...</item>
        <item name="boxStrokeColor">...</item>
    </style>

    <style name="CustomTextInputEditText">
        <item name="android:textAppearance">...</item>
        <item name="android:paddingTop">@dimen/margin_12</item>
        <item name="android:paddingBottom">@dimen/margin_12</item>
        <item name="android:paddingStart">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingEnd">0dp</item>
    </style>
```

these 2 lines sets vertical offset for title/hint view in expanded state over collapsed state:

```
  <item name="boxCollapsedPaddingTop">-16dp</item>
  <item name="android:paddingTop">16dp</item>
```

these 2 lines - for margin between text and underline:

```
  <item name="android:paddingTop">@dimen/margin_12</item>
  <item name="android:paddingBottom">@dimen/margin_12</item>
```

that line - for removing backround tint bug:

```
 <item name="boxBackgroundColor">@color/backgroundColorWhite</item>
```

these 2 lines - for removing standard horizontal paddings

```
 <item name="android:paddingStart">0dp</item>
 <item name="android:paddingEnd">0dp</item>
```

Answer (score 3):

I made a special class for the purpose of adding empty view above EditText, thus add padding to hint. You can use it as simple TextInputLayout.

```
public class PaddingTextInputLayout extends TextInputLayout {

public View paddingView;

public PaddingTextInputLayout(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public PaddingTextInputLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public PaddingTextInputLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
}

@Override
public void addView(View child, int index, ViewGroup.LayoutParams params) {
    super.addView(child, index, params);
    refreshPaddingView();
}

public void addPaddingView(){
    paddingView = new View(getContext());
    int height = (int) getContext().getResources()
            .getDimension(R.dimen.edittext_text_input_layout_padding);
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams paddingParams = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            height);
    super.addView(paddingView, 0, paddingParams);
}

public void refreshPaddingView(){
    if (paddingView != null) {
        removeView(paddingView);
        paddingView = null;
    }
    addPaddingView();
}
}
```

This implementation is very simple and stupid, you can improve it a lot.

Comment: Works well for me.

Answer (score 3):

To disable the bottom line cut effect i have used margins, translationY and clipChildren="false"

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/textinput"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:clipChildren="false">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/et_profile_contact_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="3dp"
            android:background="@drawable/image_back"
            android:hint="Contact name"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:translationY="3dp" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what i did in my project for getting enough space between edittext and hint

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/til_full_name"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:textColorHint="#fff"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/welcome_til_email">

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
        android:id="@+id/et_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="#9a050505"
        android:hint="You email"
        android:inputType="textCapWords"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:top="10dp"
          android:bottom="5dp">
        <shape>
            <!-- Background Color -->
            <solid android:color="#f1f1f1"/>
            <!-- Round Corners -->
            <corners android:radius="5dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>

<style name="text_input_edit_text_without_border_style">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">55dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingTop">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">5dp</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">left|center_vertical</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">8dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">8dp</item>
    <item name="android:maxLines">1</item>
    <item name="android:singleLine">true</item>
    <item name="android:imeOptions">actionNext</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/text_size_large</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/bg_without_border_with_padding_top</item>
</style>

<style name="text_input_layout_style">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">@dimen/margin_medium</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add to your EditText custom background

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <padding
                android:top="4dp"/> // your padding value
        </shape>
    </item>
// customize your background items if you need
</layer-list>
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
 ...>
    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
        ...
        android:background="@style/your_custom_background"/>
```

then apply it to your EditText and increase height of your EditText with your padding value if you use fix height

Answer (score 1):

This a late answer but hope it helps, And I thinks its a bit better solution. Rather then giving background to your `editText` , Give that background to your `TextInputLayout` . And set `edittext` layout to transparent.

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/tinput_phone"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="05dp"
                android:background="@drawable/send_email_screen_element_bg"
                android:padding="05dp"
                android:theme="@style/grey_control_style">

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
                    android:id="@+id/edt_phone"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:hint="@string/phone_hint_str"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:paddingStart="10dp"
                    android:paddingTop="10dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

just use padding-bottom

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout



             app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                >

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText

                   ....
                    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/dp_25"
...
                   />
            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set the `android:hint` padding to 0 on focus, add `app:boxCollapsedPaddingTop="0dp"` to your `TextInputLayout`.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use paddingStart instead of padding left or right. It worked for me.

```
android:paddingStart="8dp"
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Erkan for `app:boxCollapsedPaddingTop` (if `background` is set in `TextInputLayout`).

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingHorizontal="16dp"
    android:paddingVertical="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_corners"
    app:boxStrokeWidth="0dp"
    app:boxStrokeWidthFocused="0dp"
    app:boxCollapsedPaddingTop="8dp">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingHorizontal="0dp"
        android:paddingVertical="8dp"
        android:hint="Hint" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

[image]

But if you set `background` in `TextInputEditText`, nothing more is required. It even works nice for error state.

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:boxStrokeWidth="0dp"
    app:boxStrokeWidthFocused="0dp">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_corners"
        android:hint="Hint" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the requirement is to add space between cursor and hint then you can try

```
editTextComment.setHint("  "+getString(R.string.add_a_comment));
```

Answer (score 0):

**layout xml**

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    style="@style/TextInputLayout"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:theme="@style/TextInputLayoutHint">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
        style="@style/TextInputEditText"
        android:hint="Email ID"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:maxLines="1" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

**styles.xml**

```
<style name="TextInputLayout">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginStart">15dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">15dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginTop">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginEnd">15dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginRight">15dp</item>
</style>

<style name="TextInputLayoutHint" parent="">
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/colorHintNormal</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/colorOrange</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">11dp</item>
</style>

<style name="TextInputEditText" parent="">
    <item name="android:translationY">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:background">@null</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">15dp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorBlack</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/colorHintActive</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">13sp</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `startIconDrawable` to `TextInputLayout` and make sure you set some dummy transparant icon(icon width would be the padding start value). so that you will get padding from start.
Note: this is a hack, not a direct solution

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution and editTextStyle in TextInputLayout style only. For example:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    ...
    android:layout_width="@dimen/element_width"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/element_height"
    ...
    style="@style/EditTextField.Container"
    ...
    android:hint="@string/you_hint_resource">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        ...
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        ... />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

In your style section

```
<style name="EditTextField"/>

<style name="EditTextField.Container" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox.Dense">
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/edit_text_hint_color</item>
    <item name="hintTextColor">@color/edit_text_hint_color</item>
    <item name="hintTextAppearance">@style/PasswordInput.HintTextAppearance</item>
    <item name="materialThemeOverlay">@style/PasswordInput.MaterialThemeOverlayStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="EditTextField.HintTextAppearance">
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">20dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingTop">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
</style>

<style name="EditTextField.MaterialThemeOverlayStyle">
    <item name="editTextStyle">@style/EditTextStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="EditTextStyle" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputEditText.FilledBox.Dense">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/edittext_body_container</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">@dimen/input_text_bottom_padding</item>
    <item name="android:paddingStart">@dimen/input_text_padding_start</item>
    <item name="android:paddingTop">@dimen/input_text_top_padding</item>
    <item name="android:textCursorDrawable">@drawable/cursor_white_drawable</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
    <item name="lineHeight">20sp</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Working Solution:**

You have to give custom height to TextInputEditText and make a custom drawable then you will get your solution, **HOPE IT WILL WORKS 100%**

> 1st step:

```
 <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/tilStart"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:textColorHint="@color/darkgreen"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_20sdp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:errorEnabled="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/labelDescription">

  <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
      android:id="@+id/tietStart"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="@dimen/_30sdp"
      android:hint="@string/start_offset"
      android:fontFamily="@font/gilroysemibold"
      android:background="@drawable/customedittext"
      android:text="@string/zero"
      android:gravity="bottom"
      android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_10sdp"
      android:textColor="@color/darkgreen"
      android:inputType="number"
      android:typeface="monospace"
      android:digits="0123456789."
      android:singleLine="true" />
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

> 2nd step:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:top="@dimen/_10sdp">
    <shape >
        <solid android:color="@color/activitycolor"/>
        <corners android:radius="@dimen/_10sdp"/>
    </shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you should consider this:

The design library takes an interesting approach to customizing the `EditText`: it doesn’t change it directly. Instead, the `TextInputLayout` is used to wrap the `EditText` and provide the enhancements.

The first one, displaying a floating label when the user types something into the field, is done automagically. The `TextInputLayout` finds the `EditText` among its children and attaches itself as a `TextWatcher`, so it’s able to determine when the field has been modified and animates the movement of the hint from its regular place in the `EditText` to the floating label position above it.

The second enhancement, displaying the error message, requires a slight change in code. Instead of setting the error on the EditText, the error should be set on the `TextInputLayout`. That’s because there is no automatic way for the `TextInputLayout` to be notified when the error is set on the `EditText`.
Here’s what the layout might look like:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/username_text_input_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/username_edit_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/username_hint"/>
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Note that both the `EditText` and `TextInputLayout` need layout IDs. In the fragment, we would need to configure the `TextInputLayout` to enable displaying errors:

```
TextInputLayout usernameTextInputLayout = (TextInputLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.username_text_input_layout);
usernameTextInputLayout.setErrorEnabled(true);
...
usernameTextInputLayout.setError(R.string.username_required);
```

Comment: let the hint appear in the Edit text

Comment: No that not what i want,I use background to edit text its expand edittext border beyond its default limit so that hint overlapping the edittext.
Is there any method or xml tag that can make margin between Hint and Edittext upper border?

Comment: android:paddingTop="20dp"  or what ever suit you

Comment: and remove this tag 
android:layout_marginTop="10dp"  in your TextinputLayout

Comment: Not working android:paddingTop="20dp"  also because its make space inside EditText i want to make space Between Hint and Edittext...

Comment: dud by setting paddingTop working for me , I have jsut tested ,

Comment: just remove your background for a second and then test it

Comment: see this link , if we can reduce distance then we can also increase the padding , and As I tried giving padding top , really works for me, I think the problem is your background 

here is the link :   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30946041/how-do-you-reduce-space-between-floating-edittext-hint-and-edittext-box-in-andro

Comment: Background is mandatory when i use background to EditText then its default border limit is exceeds so i want to know is there any xml attribute or java method that can make vertical distance between hint and EditText.

Comment: I was just saying you to make it confirm that your background creating problem , why dont you make your background smaller in height

Comment: I changed the height but that doesn't make any difference.Still issue remaining because image doesn't contain any transparent area in upper and bottom.

Comment: can you please remove background and then try again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89880/discussion-between-coas-mckey-and-pranav).