# TextInputLayout hint padding not working

Tags: android, textinputlayout

I want to give padding to hint of edittext in TextInputLayout

where email address is hint and Sample is text

[image]

also tried [this  solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32609710/textinputlayout-how-to-give-padding-or-margin-to-hint) but didn't work.

facing this issue after changing support design library 23.1.0

here is my code

```
       <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp">

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
                android:id="@+id/edtEmailAddress"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/border_round_edt_grey"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:hint="@string/emailadd"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:singleLine="true" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 8):

As per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32609710/textinputlayout-how-to-give-padding-or-margin-to-hint) answer ,**if you have custom background set on EditText the android:padding attribute simple doesn't work to alter the spacing b/w the hint text and edit text** .So if you have set custom background to your AppCompatEditText, you can use `android:translationY` attribute in the AppCompatEditText

Please add below line in your `AppCompatEditText`.

```
android:translationY="10dp"
```

hope you got your answer :)

Comment: thanks its working.!! with `android:translationY="2dp"`

Comment: hi,when i try the android:translationY="10dp"  these lines it hide the bottom edittext border how to resolve it?