# TextInputLayout error text padding

Tags: android, material-design, android-appcompat, android-textinputlayout

I am using **TextInputLayout** with **AppCompatEditText** having a custom xml shape based background for **AppCompatEditText**. Whenever i set some error , the error line starts from beginning of layout. Is there any way to give padding to that error line.

[image]

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32609710/textinputlayout-how-to-give-padding-or-margin-to-hint

Comment: Could you update this question with code that you tried?

Comment: Using `setError(null)`

Comment: Remove background image to EditText it solve your problem background image to the EditText Creat this problem

Answer (score 6):

You can reference error TextView by using:

```
TextView textView = (TextView) inputLayout.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id
            .textinput_error);
```

Then you can get its layout params to work with.

Comment: risky hack is risky. at the same time tho, I don't think the id would change anytime soon

Comment: Keep in mind that the error text view is created only when error is displayed, so you need to change params after you display an error in your TextInputLayout.

Answer (score 2):

I struggled to solve this and this is what worked for me:

Removing the padding on the parent of the parent of my error textview

Using [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48952311/1399928) I could find the error textview (cause I needed to add an icon to it) but couldn´t get rid of the padding, so after a few tries I realized that TextInputLayout has 2 childs so removing the padding from the second child did the trick
and just to be sure, I removed it also from the first one

Using Kotlin extensions I came up with a clean solution

```html
/**
 * TextInputLayout
 */
fun TextInputLayout.removePadding() {
    for (i in 0 until this.childCount) {
        this.getChildAt(i).setPadding(0)
    }
}
```

You can do it also in java using the same logic.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/tx_in_username"
    android:errorEnabled="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_LEFT_RIGHT"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_LEFT_RIGHT"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_height="36sp"
    android:hint="Username"
    />
```

Comment: for Inner EditText Don't Use marginLeft and marginRight