# TextInputLayout error message size

Tags: android, text-size, android-textinputlayout

Is there a way to force the TextInputLayout error message to take a single line ?

I tried to place `app:errorTextAppearance="@style/error_appearance"` on the TextInputLayout with the error_appearance style containing :

```
<item name="android:maxLines">1</item>
<item name="android:ellipsize">end</item>
<item name="android:inputType">text</item>
```

and it does not work. Changing the color works however. I don't get it, the mErrorView is just a TextView, it should work.

[image: TextInputLayout error message]

Answer (score 9):

you can fetch error TextView by id

```
TextView errorView = textInputLayout.findViewById(R.id.textinput_error);
errorView.setMaxLines(1);
errorView.setSingleLine(true);
```

Comment: Worked for me, but keep in mind that in order to find the view properly, the attribute **errorEnabled** must be set to **true** on xml for the class to instantiate the TextView upon creation

Answer (score 7):

It's true the the error is a `TextView`, but a `TextAppearance` style affects only text, not the `View` that the text is in. The `maxLines` and `ellipsize` attributes belong to `TextView`, so they will be ignored in a `TextAppearance` style, which expects attributes like `textColor`, `textSize`, `typeface`, etc.<sup>1</sup>

Knowing this, we just need to find a way to set those attributes' values on the error `TextView`. [kjurkovic's answer on this very question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48952311)
shows how to do that in code, for the current versions of `TextInputLayout`.<sup>2</sup> It turns out that there's also a way we can do this in the layout XML, which might be preferable for some.

That error `TextView` is instantiated with the `TextInputLayout`'s `Context`, which we can actually modify in the layout XML, to some extent, with the `android:theme` attribute. Using an overlay with this attribute, we can cause that `Context`'s theme to have an `android:textViewStyle` – essentially, the basic settings for `TextView`s – that contains our desired attribute values.

In your theme/style resource XML:

```xml
<style name="ThemeOverlay.TextInputLayout.TextView" parent="">
    <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/Widget.TextView.SingleLineEllipsized</item>
</style>

<style name="Widget.TextView.SingleLineEllipsized" parent="">
    <item name="android:maxLines">1</item>
    <item name="android:ellipsize">end</item>
</style>
```

On the `<TextInputLayout>` in the layout XML, simply add the `android:theme` attribute:

```xml
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/text_input_layout_phone"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Phone number"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.TextInputLayout.TextView">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_text_phone"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Though the current `TextInputLayout` has different design details than the original, we can see that the `maxLines` and `ellipsize` settings have worked:

[image]

---

The main caveat with this approach is that all of `TextInputLayout`'s internal `TextView`s will have these base attribute values. Currently, aside from the error, those comprise the helper, the counter, the prefix, and the suffix.

- The helper occupies the same spot as the error, so if you want single-line-and-ellipsized on one, you very likely want it on the other as well, if you're even using it.
- The counter is already being set up as single-line, and the extraneous `ellipsize` would only have effect if the counter were to grow wider than the `EditText`.
- The prefix and the suffix, by their nature, are meant to be single-line anyway.

If any of that is undesired, then kjurkovic's `findViewById()` demonstration should work with all of those `TextView`s,<sup>3</sup> though you must ensure to set the corresponding text first, as the `TextView`s are instantiated on demand.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> You can find the full list of valid `TextAppearance` attributes in [the platform's `res/values/attrs.xml` resource file](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/3c2fc6f7427e84d32a8c0ca59b4b0b981da2f1a8/core/res/res/values/attrs.xml#4723). I don't believe there is any documentation or developer page that covers it; at least, there didn't used to be.</sup>

<sup><sup>2</sup> The very first versions of `TextInputLayout` did not assign IDs to the inner `TextView`s, so getting direct reference to the error `TextView` required reflection, or awkwardly searching the internal hierarchy. I've not tested the theme overlay solution on those ancient versions, but if for whatever reason you're stuck with one and this doesn't work, [previous revisions of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/40706872/revisions) have those other options for you.</sup>

<sup><sup>3</sup> Incidentally, the IDs for all of those are as follows: `R.id.textinput_error`, `R.id.textinput_helper_text`, `R.id.textinput_counter`, `R.id.textinput_prefix_text`, and `R.id.textinput_suffix_text`.</sup>

Comment: Dude, you're a genius.. Worked like a charm.. Thanks a ton man.