# TextInputLayout Error right align

Tags: android, layout, textinputlayout

I've an EditText enclosed within a TextInputLayout. I wish to display errors under the EditText, but aligned to the right end of the screen.

This is what I currently have:
[image: Text Input Layout]

The error is displayed like this:
[image: Error right now]

What I want it to look like:
[image: What I want]

My XML is this:

```
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/text_input_email"
            style="@style/forgot_pass_text_inputlayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/tv_enter_email_message"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/email_padding_top"
            android:hintTextAppearance="@{forgotPasswordVM.hintTextAppearance}"
            android:theme="@style/forgot_pass_til_state"
            app:error="@{forgotPasswordVM.email.textInputError}">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/actv_email"
                style="@style/forgot_pass_edit_text"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/email_address"
                android:imeActionId="@+id/btn_submit"
                android:imeOptions="actionSend"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:onEditorAction="@{forgotPasswordVM.onEditorAction}"
                android:singleLine="true"
                app:binding="@{forgotPasswordVM.email.text}" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

I'm using data-binding.

I've tried setting `android:gravity="right"` and `android:layout_gravity="right"` on both the EditText and the TextInputLayout. Neither works the way I want it to.

I've tried setting right gravity in the theme as well as the style. Neither has any effect on the error.

I've tried right gravity on the style that is applied within `app:errorTextAppearance="@style/right_error"`. Even this doesn't work.

I tried programmatically shifting the Error to the right by using a SpannableStringBuilder with an AlignmentSpan following [this link](https://gist.github.com/slightfoot/171f5002d06089cae460). Even that doesn't work for me.

I'm not sure what else to try. Please suggest.

Comment: You might try using one of the options in [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40706872) to get the error `TextView`, and call `setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT)` on it. I've not tested it, but IIRC, the error `TextView` has a `match_parent` width, so it should align its text as you describe.

Comment: Good suggestion Mike M. but I tried both RIGHT and END to no avail.  Had to go with the programmatic approach detailed below ...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65991884/4718406

Answer (score 12, accepted):

So thanks to [Mike's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40706872/3286614) I was able to figure out the solution.

I created a custom class:

```
public class CustomTextInputLayout extends TextInputLayout {

    public CustomTextInputLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public void setErrorEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        super.setErrorEnabled(enabled);

        if (!enabled) {
            return;
        }

        try {
            Field errorViewField = TextInputLayout.class.getDeclaredField("mErrorView");
            errorViewField.setAccessible(true);
            TextView errorView = (TextView) errorViewField.get(this);
            if (errorView != null) {
                errorView.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                params.gravity = Gravity.END;
                errorView.setLayoutParams(params);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            // At least log what went wrong
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Now I simply replaced my TextInputLayout with the CustomTextInputLayout.
Works like a charm. Thanks a lot [Mike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2850651/mike-m). I wish I could credit you more for this answer.

Comment: hi,im trying to show the error message ON the edittext and right aligned corner,any idea how i do that?

Comment: @ViVekH, can you explain a little more as to what you want?

Comment: This doesn't appear to work any longer (or, certainly not on a 3.3.2 / Android 9 setup).

Comment: That doesn't work for me.
I've supportsRtl disabled it in the manifest. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 5):

Here's a hack in Kotlin that doesn't depend on view hierarchy:

```
class CustomTextInputLayout @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null, defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : TextInputLayout(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {

    override fun setError(errorText: CharSequence?) {
        super.setError(errorText)
        with(findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textinput_error)) {
            // this will work as long as errorView's layout width is
            // MATCH_PARENT -- it is, at least now in material:1.2.0-alpha06
            textAlignment = TextView.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_VIEW_END
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it helped me a lot. If someone wants to use this with view binding, just do as follows: 

`with(binding.root.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textinput_error)) {textAlignment = TextView.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER}`

Answer (score 4):

My custom class is in Kotlin

```
class CustomTextInputLayout(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) :
    TextInputLayout(context, attrs) {

    override fun setErrorEnabled(enabled: Boolean) {
        super.setErrorEnabled(enabled)

        if (!enabled) {
            return
        }

        try {
            val layout = this
            val errorView : TextView = ((this.getChildAt(1) as ViewGroup).getChildAt(0) as ViewGroup).getChildAt(0) as TextView

            (layout.getChildAt(1) as ViewGroup).layoutParams.width = LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
            (layout.getChildAt(1) as ViewGroup).getChildAt(0).layoutParams.width = FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT

            errorView.gravity = Gravity.END

        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: This works for now (2019-02-18), but it will stop working when the view hierarchy changes again.

Answer (score 3):

With material-componets version `1.2.0-rc01`, you can create a CustomTextInputLayout that inherits from TextInputLayout to change the **text alignment** to the end (or where you want it to be) like this:

```
class CustomTextInputLayout : TextInputLayout {

    constructor(context: Context) : super(context)

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) : super(context, attrs)

    constructor(
        context: Context,
        attrs: AttributeSet?,
        defStyleAttrs: Int
    ) : super(context, attrs, defStyleAttrs)

    override fun setErrorEnabled(enabled: Boolean) {
        super.setErrorEnabled(enabled)
        if (!enabled) {
            return
        }
        try {
            changeTextAlignment(
                com.google.android.material.R.id.textinput_error,
                View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_VIEW_END
            )
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }

   
    private fun changeTextAlignment(textViewId: Int, alignment: Int) {
        val textView = findViewById<TextView>(textViewId)
        textView.textAlignment = alignment
    }
}
```

The alignment is specified in the `IndicatorViewController` class to always be `View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_VIEW_START`. This class is used by the TextInputLayout.

From the `IndicatorViewController` class

```
  void setErrorEnabled(boolean enabled) {
    if (errorEnabled == enabled) {
      return;
    }

    cancelCaptionAnimator();

    if (enabled) {
      errorView = new AppCompatTextView(context);
      errorView.setId(R.id.textinput_error);
      if (VERSION.SDK_INT >= 17) {
        errorView.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_VIEW_START);
      }
//More code...
```

Answer (score 0):

If selected answer not works. Another solution is below:

Create custom class as below:

```
public class CustomTextInputLayout extends TextInputLayout
{

public CustomTextInputLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
{
    super(context, attrs);
}

@Override
public void setErrorEnabled(boolean enabled)
{
    super.setErrorEnabled(enabled);

    if (!enabled)
    {
        return;
    }

    try
    {
        TextView errorView = this.findViewById(R.id.textinput_error);
        FrameLayout errorViewParent = (FrameLayout) errorView.getParent();
        errorViewParent.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        errorView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER); // replace CENTER  with END or RIGHT
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Then create your custom TextInputLayout as:

```
 <CustomTextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/til_first_name"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/til_last_name">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_first_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/first_name"
        android:gravity="right"
        />

</CustomTextInputLayout>
```

After that initialize in your code as:

```
private CustomTextInputLayout tilFirstName;
tilFirstName = view.findViewById(R.id.til_first_name);
```

Congratulations! You have done what you have required.

Comment: Thats basically textview in which error is shown of textinputlayout.

Comment: I think the id should be `com.google.android.material.R.id.textinput_error`, otherwise it will complain R not found

Comment: Brother I have above working code. Its working fine.

Comment: Android Studio complains about your code on my end. Unless you import `com.google.android.material.R`, which you should mention it in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Based on **@Emmanuel Guerra**'s answer. I've applied it on helperText too:

```
class CustomTextInputLayout @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyleAttr: Int = com.google.android.material.R.attr.textInputStyle
) : TextInputLayout(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {

    override fun setErrorEnabled(enabled: Boolean) {
        super.setErrorEnabled(enabled)
        if (!enabled) return
        centerMiniText(com.google.android.material.R.id.textinput_error)
    }

    override fun setHelperTextEnabled(enabled: Boolean) {
        super.setHelperTextEnabled(enabled)
        if (!enabled) return
        centerMiniText(com.google.android.material.R.id.textinput_helper_text)
    }

    private fun centerMiniText(textViewId: Int) {
        try {
            changeTextAlignment(textViewId, View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }

    @Suppress("SameParameterValue")
    private fun changeTextAlignment(textViewId: Int, alignment: Int) {
        findViewById<TextView>(textViewId)?.textAlignment = alignment
    }

}
```