# How to set gravity for TextInputLayout's error message

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, android-textinputlayout

I am using **TextInputLayout** to show error message. By default, TextInputLayout's  setError() shows error text at the bottom of it. Please refer to No1 Image. Now, accordingly to my designer design, I have to show it at the top of TextInputLayout(pls see No2 Image). I'm now thinking to create custom view here but in the whole project, I have to change many places manually. So, let me know if we can set **Gravity for the TextInputLayout error message** at the Top. Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: This might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42575825/textinputlayout-error-right-align

Comment: @AskNilesh I have tried it. It only set gravity to start/center or end. Top gravity won't working. It always show under edittext.

Comment: May be you can change gravity but more complex to top moving... Debug viewgroup hirarcecy otherwise add your own text view...

Comment: @GobuCSG now I'm adding my custom view in every place :3

Comment: I think that's better.