# TextInputLayout error text align right not working

Tags: android, android-textinputlayout

As per design I require `TextInputLayout` error text at right side, explored and tried below style, but didn't success.

```
<style name="Theme.Input" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox">
        <item name="hintEnabled">false</item>
        <item name="boxCornerRadiusBottomEnd">@dimen/input_box_corner_radius</item>
        <item name="boxCornerRadiusBottomStart">@dimen/input_box_corner_radius</item>
        <item name="boxCornerRadiusTopEnd">@dimen/input_box_corner_radius</item>
        <item name="boxCornerRadiusTopStart">@dimen/input_box_corner_radius</item>
        <item name="errorEnabled">true</item>
        <item name="errorTextColor">@color/red</item>
        <item name="boxStrokeErrorColor">@color/red</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorInputText</item>
        <item name="iconEndPadding">@dimen/std_16dp</item>
        <item name="errorTextAppearance">@style/Theme.EZazi.Input.Error</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/input_inner_size</item>
        <item name="boxStrokeWidth">@dimen/input_stroke_size</item>
        <item name="boxStrokeWidthFocused">@dimen/input_stroke_size</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Theme.Input.Error" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Error">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/red</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/caption</item>
        <item name="android:textAlignment">viewEnd</item>
    </style>
```

See, what I want to achieve as per design

[image: Right align error]

After apply theme it still at left side.

[image: Applied theme result]

Also tried with custom methodology.

```
public class RightAlignErrorTextInputLayout extends TextInputLayout {
    public RightAlignErrorTextInputLayout(@NonNull Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public RightAlignErrorTextInputLayout(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public RightAlignErrorTextInputLayout(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init();
    }

    private void init(){
        setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_VIEW_END);
    }

    @Override
    public void setErrorEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        super.setErrorEnabled(enabled);

        if (!enabled) {
            return;
        }

        try {
            Field errorViewField = TextInputLayout.class.getDeclaredField("mErrorView");
            errorViewField.setAccessible(true);
            TextView errorView = (TextView) errorViewField.get(this);
            if (errorView != null) {
                errorView.setGravity(Gravity.END);
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                params.gravity = Gravity.END;
                errorView.setLayoutParams(params);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            // At least log what went wrong
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone help to achieve error text at right side with `TextInputLayout`?

Your help will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: You'll probably need to create your own custom TextInputLayout. This post may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/q/42575825/8192914

Answer (score 0):

I would like to share the simple solution for this my own question.

```
public class RightAlignErrorTextInputLayout extends TextInputLayout {
private static final String TAG = "TextInputLayout";

public RightAlignErrorTextInputLayout(@NonNull Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}

public RightAlignErrorTextInputLayout(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
}

public RightAlignErrorTextInputLayout(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    init();
}

private void init() {
    setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_VIEW_END);
}

@Override
public void setErrorEnabled(boolean enabled) {
    super.setErrorEnabled(enabled);
    TextView errorView = findViewById(R.id.textinput_error);
    if (errorView != null) errorView.setTextAlignment(TextView.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_VIEW_END);
}

@Override
public void setError(@Nullable CharSequence errorText) {
    super.setError(errorText);
    TextView errorView = findViewById(R.id.textinput_error);
    if (errorView != null) errorView.setTextAlignment(TextView.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_VIEW_END);
}
}
```