# How to create a custom text input layout like material 3 in android, Because for me existing material 3 and material 2 not satisfying the requirement

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, android-custom-view, material-components-android

I got requirement from designer for custom edit text or input text layout, so for that i tried to look in to MD2 and MD3 documentation, But i didn't found anything useful.

[image: Text Input layout requirement]

This is the requirement, its similar to material design 3 text input layout but not same. How i can acheive this

I tried to find solution from internet, MD2 and MD3 documentation for that custom text input layout but didn't found.

Need help to achieve the design

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way I am aware of, is using an unicoded text in error text.

```
// Set error text
inputLayout.error = "\U+00A9" + "  ERROR TEXT"
```

Using [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67525797/6576302) you can change error field padding. There, I don't know how he have implemented what you want. but due to my search, there is ALMOST no way to do this. one can access to error `TextView` using

```
inputLayout.findViewById(R.id.textinput_error)
```

but trying to add drawable to it, is not helpful.