# How to change spacing between hint and underline of EditText inside TextInputLayout?

Tags: android, textinputlayout

I want to change the spacing between the hint and underline. I am using EditText inside TextInputLayout. margin padding on EdiText or TextInputLayout not working. It change the entire content side instead of the spacing between hint and underline.

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:hint="Email"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />
```

Comment: use `android:paddingBottom="10dp"` in your `EditText`.

Comment: Please go through this answer. [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32822088/1733844)