# Set padding and margin to Hint in Customized EditText

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have 2 got customized edittext.I also have a hint to it.How do I set padding to the hint?[image]

edittext.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle"
            >
            <solid android:color="#ffffff"
                />
            <corners android:radius="10dp"
                />
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#ffa500"
                />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>

<EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/etemail"
        android:hint="Rally Username"
        android:layout_above="@+id/etpassword"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:background="@drawable/edittext"
        android:padding="1dp"
        android:textAlignment="viewStart" />
```

In that I want Rally Username and rally Password to 2 or 3 dp to left?How do I achieve that??
Thanks

Comment: Try this solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/33435984/3946958

Comment: What `@drawable/edittext` contains ?

Comment: it is the xml file..see my edit

Comment: add  android:paddingLeft="10dp"

Answer (score 2):

Hello Change your selector and add padding to it

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle"
    >
        <solid android:color="#ffffff"
        />
        <corners android:radius="10dp"
        />
        <padding android:bottom="10dp"
                 android:left="10dp"
                 android:right="10dp"
                 android:top="10dp"/>
        <stroke
            android:width="1dp"
            android:color="#ffa500"
        />
    </shape>
</item>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have edited your EditText.

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/etemail"
    android:hint="Rally Username"
    android:layout_above="@+id/etpassword"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_margin="2dp"
    android:background="@drawable/edittext"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="1dp"
    android:paddingBottom="1dp"
    android:textAlignment="viewStart" />
```