# How to set difference padding for text/title/error at the TextInputLayout?

Tags: android, android-textinputlayout

I have the TextInputLayout which by default have similar paddings at the text/title/error but I need to have different paddings for each of them.

```
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/base_exit_text"
                android:paddingLeft="16dp"
                android:paddingTop="22dp"
                android:paddingRight="16dp"
                android:paddingBottom="16dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

What I have:

[image: What I have]

What I need:

[image: What I need]

Comment: can you please provide full XML file title so ?

Comment: Yes, here it is: https://photos.app.goo.gl/qVEKUXYn1KzTdcyq9

Comment: you didn't add BaseTextInputLayoutStyle to your view

Comment: Checkout this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32609710/textinputlayout-how-to-give-padding-or-margin-to-hint

Comment: Sorry about my little confuse(At first I tried to simplify it) Here is much real code: https://photos.app.goo.gl/bRw5MYR8rAKTTfePA

Comment: The answer you've sent is about the vertical padding but I need horizontal padding. I`m looking for the solution hot to set different left paddings to text/title/error views at the TextInputLayout