# how to set property paddingLeft of TextInputEditText in android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, text, hint

The text comes up on the photo.how to set element padding-right text from mic image

[image]

Comment: how you add that image? using drawable right? Please add your code for more detail

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32609710/textinputlayout-how-to-give-padding-or-margin-to-hint

Comment: upload your Xml code

Answer (score 0):

Instead of relying on padding, I suggest you to learn ConstraintLayout. This layout is most widely used these days. It sets constraints (like rules) for parent layout and your components. It is much better than padding, which needs to be set differently for different screen sizes and densities.

To use ConstraintLayout, follow these steps:

1. Put your `TextView` and `ImageView` under `ConstraintLayout`.
2. Select both of them and Right Click.
3. Select `Chains` -> `Create Horizontal Chain`.

This set constraints on both of the components and they will never overlap.

For in-depth understanding of ConstraintLayout, check:

- [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/ConstraintLayout) (Google Documentations)
- [Exploring the new Android ConstraintLayout](https://medium.com/exploring-android/exploring-the-new-android-constraintlayout-eed37fe8d8f1) (Medium Tutorials)