# Android TextInputLayout[hint inside the edit field not outside the border]

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, material-design

I'm trying to create TextInputLayout with hint inside the input field like this:
[image]

This is my code, I tried with OutLinedBox and Filled, If I use Filled and set a background for the layout, the position of hint is incorrect

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/my_view_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/textValue"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:hint="label">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit Answer

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/text_input_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
        android:hint="Email"
        app:boxBackgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"
        app:boxStrokeWidth="0dp"
        app:boxStrokeWidthFocused="0dp">
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/edit_text"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Selector

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/white"/>
            <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="?attr/colorPrimary"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/white"/>
            <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="?attr/colorControlNormal"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

[image]

Edit Answer 2:

The problem can be solved by adding vertical padding.

```
android:paddingVertical="yourDp"
```

[Please check for reference answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77033904/5595926)

Comment: Thanks for the response, this will not solve the issue, I need the hint to be in TextInputLayout and when the use focus the TextInputEditText the hint should go up, but I don't need it to be inside the border, I need as my provided screenshot

Comment: I'm updating my answer

Comment: That's what I tried before, it's working fine, but the hit is closed to the top border

Comment: You can get more support if you share the result image.

Comment: I'm updating my answer again

Comment: Thanks dear, solution provided with edit 2 worked fine

Comment: You're welcome.